# Json encode and special characters

Tags: php, json

My code was working fine when i was getting the data from a table without special characters, but when i tried to use the same code, on a different table, and Json returned me null values, how can i fix that, and output the data with special characters?

```
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dates");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $output[] = $row;
    }

$users = json_encode(array(
    "contacts" => $output
));
mysql_close($con);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the values null when you check them in the PHP server-side (`var_dump($users)`) or when you attempt to use the JSON in your JS client-side?

Comment: when i do var dump, everything appears, but when i just echo the json encode, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode` expects the data to be UTF-8 encoded (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)). Try getting MySQL to encode your query response as UTF-8.

```
mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dates", $con);
```

Please note that the `mysql` functions are deprecated; look into the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php%20%22mysqli) functions.

Comment: @Abc No problem. Please consider marking this answer with the checkmark if you can, I'd appreciate it. :)